# Some help to make LINQ clause properly work

Tags: c#, linq

I have this Linq to Entity query:

```
        bool? t = (from ir in Context.InspectionReview
                 join so in Context.SiteObjects on ir.ObjectId equals so.Id
                 where so.SiteRegionId == 6 && so.SiteId == 5
                 select bool?
                 ir.IsNormal
                 ).FirstOrDefault();
```

`ir.IsNormal` - is boolean value

When this condition `where so.SiteRegionId == 6 && so.SiteId == 5` not satisfied 
`t` get `null`, when I have at least one record  `ir.IsNormal ==  false` value false `t` must get `true` otherwise `t` gets `false`.

Any what do I have to change in LINQ above to make  description logic above work?
I need to make it in one LINQ query.

Comment: does your code even compile? i mean `SingleOrDefault` does not give `bool?` here.

Comment: Your variable is bool (nullable) but in your  query your selecting an object! Do you need the object or a bool value (bool I guess)?

Comment: Look at left outer join on following webpage : https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

Comment: Add some punctuation to your unclear description, and explain what you mean by *`t` must get true*. It can't get `true`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about using Any() function instead?

```
var t = (from ir in Context.InspectionReview
     join so in Context.SiteObjects on ir.ObjectId equals so.Id
     where so.SiteRegionId == 6 && so.SiteId == 5
     select new
     {
         inspReviewID = ir.Id,
         isFixed = ir.IsNormal,
         objId = so.Id
     }).Any();
```

After reading your comment I thought I might be misunderstanding your question.  However if you are trying to find out if the result as any true "IsNormal", you could always do this:

```
var t = (from ir in Context.InspectionReview
     join so in Context.SiteObjects on ir.ObjectId equals so.Id
     where so.SiteRegionId == 6 && so.SiteId == 5
     select new
     {
         inspReviewID = ir.Id,
         isFixed = ir.IsNormal,
         objId = so.Id
     }).Any(a => a.isFixed);
```

**THIRD EDIT**

After you edited your question then I revised my answer with small test snippet to prove my point.

```
public class Derp
{
    public int SiteRegionId { get; set; }
    public int SiteId { get; set; }
    public bool? IsNormal { get; set; }
}
```

I then use the Derp class to match your example:

```
List<Derp> nullDerps = new List<Derp>();
nullDerps.Add(new Derp
{
    IsNormal = null,
    SiteId = 5,
    SiteRegionId = 6
});
List<Derp> trueDerps = new List<Derp>();
trueDerps.Add(new Derp
{
    IsNormal = true,
    SiteId = 5,
    SiteRegionId = 6
});
List<Derp> falseDerps = new List<Derp>();
falseDerps.Add(new Derp
{
    IsNormal = false,
    SiteId = 5,
    SiteRegionId = 6
});

bool? firstNull = (from d in nullDerps
    where d.SiteRegionId == 6 && d.SiteId == 5
    select d.IsNormal).FirstOrDefault();
bool? firstTrue = (from d in trueDerps
    where d.SiteRegionId == 6 && d.SiteId == 5
    select d.IsNormal).FirstOrDefault();
bool? firstFalse = (from d in falseDerps
    where d.SiteRegionId == 6 && d.SiteId == 5
    select d.IsNormal).FirstOrDefault();

bool anyNull = (from d in nullDerps
    where d.SiteRegionId == 6 && d.SiteId == 5
    select d.IsNormal).Any(a => a.HasValue && a.Value);
bool anyTrue = (from d in trueDerps
    where d.SiteRegionId == 6 && d.SiteId == 5
    select d.IsNormal).Any(a => a.HasValue && a.Value);
bool anyFalse = (from d in falseDerps
    where d.SiteRegionId == 6 && d.SiteId == 5
    select d.IsNormal).Any(a => a.HasValue && a.Value);
```

Your method, using FirstOrDefault() function really doesn´t help you to catch if the boolean value is null.  Therefore you can use the Any() function where you can always ask specifically what you are looking for.  The example above yields these result:

- firstNull == null
- firstTrue == true
- firstFalse == false
- anyNull == false
- anyTrue == true
- anyFalse == false

If you are trying to get true only when IsFixed is true then Any function should be the way to go.  Again, if I am misunderstanding your question then please revise.

Comment: You can always add the where conditions into the linq query --> where so.SiteRegionId == 6 && so.SiteId == 5 && ir.IsNormal <-- or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: what if this row not setesfied: 

where so.SiteRegionId == 6 && so.SiteId == 5

will it return NULL?

Comment: @Michael I revised my answer, I hope this better explains what I meant with Any() function  :)